# How to solve Laplce equation with Dirichlet exterior?

Tags: calculus, limits, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, linear-pde

I am studying from the book of Qing Han- A Basic Course in Partial Differential Equations

Can't find any clue how to solve:
Exercise 4.8. Let $u$ be a $C^{2}$ -solution of
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta u=0 & \text { in } \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash B_{R}, \\
u=0 & \text { on } \partial B_{R} .
\end{aligned}
$$
Prove that $u \equiv 0$ if
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\lim _{|x| \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u(x)}{\ln |x|}=0 & \text { for } n=2, \\
\lim _{|x| \rightarrow \infty} u(x)=0 & \text { for } n \geq 3
\end{array}
$$

Should I look for symmetric solutions? Anything connected to the fundamental solution?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some connection with the fundamental solution. Hint: the Kelvin tramsform and a removable singularity theorem for harmonic functions.

Comment: Thank you. I am still wondering- if I am using Kelvin transform the transformed function will be harmonic in the ball. But, does it say I can still derive the fundamental solution? I guess it's due to symmetry, no?

Comment: The fundamental solution is connected  with a removable singularity theorem: if a function is harmonic in a deleted neighbourhood of some  point and grow slower than the fundamental solution at the point, then the function is harmonic in the whole neighbourhood. That's the only use of the f.s. here.